# Issue with passing environment variable to make file

Tags: makefile, command-line-arguments

In my make file I have 2 parameters defined as below with default values.
PARAM1 ?= 2
PARAM2 ?= 11
I am using these parameters in my target cpp_run.

```
cpp_run:
    ./dig_vr_App $(PARAM1) $(PARAM2) |& tee run_Cpp.log
```

However if I pass the parameters from the command line for example

```
make cpp_run PARAM1=102 PARAM2=0
```

the make file still picks up the default values, i.e., 2 and 11 (from the log file run_cpp.log). I followed other posts which says use PARAM1=num1 and PARAM2=num2 in the command line as shown above but it doesn't work.

Comment: What you describe is not possible, so there must be something else going on that you haven't shown us.  For one thing you say "from run_Cpp.log", but what are the actual values that were used?  Make will print the command line, so does the output say `./dig_vr_App 2 11`?  Or does it say `./dig_vr_App 102 0`?  If the latter the problem is not with make or make variables, because make is passing the right values to the program.

Comment: One thing to note: the syntax `|&` is bash-specific and not portable to other shells and make always invokes `/bin/sh` by default.  If `/bin/sh` on your system is not bash, this won't work.  You should use the portable syntax `2>&1 |` instead.

Comment: the output is ./dig_vr_App 2 11 all the time irrespective of PARAM1 and PARAM2 values I try to pass through the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comments, you are not telling us something.  I created this test:

```
$ cat Makefile
PARAM1 ?= 2
PARAM2 ?= 11

cpp_run:
         @echo ./dig_vr_App $(PARAM1) $(PARAM2)
```

and it works exactly how I'd expect:

```
$ make --version | head -n2
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

$ make cpp_run
./dig_vr_App 2 11

$ make cpp_run PARAM1=102 PARAM2=0
./dig_vr_App 102 0
```

So there's something about your environment or makefile that you haven't explained to us.

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I overlooked the log file. In fact change in the PARAMs are reflecting but I was expecting different .cda files (Below one) each time when I change the parameters. However  every time I see the same file name. My bad, I linked this issue with cpp_run target. `export CDA_FILE              := $(CCOV_STATS_DIR)/$(PARAM1)_$(PARAM2).ccov.cda` --> This is in my Makefile. I will try to figure out why new files are not generating.